# Is it possible to show hidden elements in XAML designer for WPF in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-2019, xaml-designer

In WinForms designer hidden elements are still shown in designer, which makes perfect sense to me as I want to be able to edit and see the element without switching its visibility all the time. In WPF XAML designer visibility property hides the element completely. I absolutely cannot get the idea of this feature, **especially** because there is designer `IsHidden` directive, which let us control the visibility of elements in designer.

Is it possible to show hidden elements in XAML designer somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
xmlns:cm="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=PresentationFramework"

<Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="boolToVisibility"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Button Visibility="{Binding (cm:DesignerProperties.IsInDesignMode), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibility}}"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: It works perfectly. I am a complete newbie in xaml, is it possible to create some kind of alias to this? It would be inconvenient to use this a lot of times in the code (and I will probably need it a lot).